# Main program not recognizing my class method java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I asked a question about this previously but I wasn't able to resolve it. I'm trying to create an array of `Supplements` (class) and store it in a single object of `Magazine` (class). When trying to call my `fillArray` method, I get the error :

```
cannot find symbol: 
symbol: method fillArray(Supplement[])
location: javaapplication1
```

What could be the issue with this?

`Supplement.java`:

```
//
    //
    //  Generated by StarUML(tm) Java Add-In
    //
    //  @ Project : Untitled
    //  @ File Name : Supplement.java
    //  @ Date : 21/04/2020
    //  @ Author : 
    //
    //

    package javaapplication1;


    public class Supplement {
        private String supplementname;
        private int WeeklySupCost;

            public void fillArray(Supplement[] supplements2){


                supplements2[0] = new Supplement("Sports Illustrated Special", 4);
                supplements2[1] = new Supplement("Health and Nutrition", 2);
                supplements2[2] = new Supplement("Lifestyled", 5);
                supplements2[3] = new Supplement("Gamer's Update", 3);


             };

            public void SetSupplementName(String supplementname1){

                supplementname = supplementname1;

            };
        public void WeeklySupCost(int WeeklySupCost1){

                WeeklySupCost = WeeklySupCost1;

            };
        public String GetSupplementName(){

                return supplementname;

            };
        public int GetWeeklyCost(){

                return WeeklySupCost;

            };
        public void SetSupplement(String supplementname1, int WeeklySupCost1){

                supplementname = supplementname1;

            };
        public Supplement(String supplementname1, int WeeklySupCost1){

                SetSupplement(supplementname1, WeeklySupCost1);

            };

            public Supplement(){};
    }
```

`Magazine.java`:

```
    //
    //
    //  Generated by StarUML(tm) Java Add-In
    //
    //  @ Project : Untitled
    //  @ File Name : Magazine.java
    //  @ Date : 21/04/2020
    //  @ Author : 
    //
    //
    package javaapplication1;

    public class Magazine {
        private String magazinename;
        private int WeeklyCost;
        private Magazine magazineobj;
        private Supplement[] supplements;

        public void SetMagazineName(String magazinename1){

            magazinename = magazinename1;

        };
        public void SetWeeklyCost(int WeeklyCost1){

            WeeklyCost = WeeklyCost1;

        };
        public String GetMagazineName(){

            return magazinename;

        };
        public int GetWeeklyCost(){

            return WeeklyCost;

        };
        public void SetMagazine(String magazinename1, int WeeklyCost1, Supplement[] supplements1){

            magazinename = magazinename1;
            WeeklyCost = WeeklyCost1;
            supplements = supplements1;

        };
        public Magazine(String magazinename1, int WeeklyCost1, Supplement[] supplements1){

            SetMagazine(magazinename1,WeeklyCost1,supplements1);

        };

        public Magazine(){};
        public void printMagazine(){

            System.out.println(magazineobj);

        }
    }
```

Main program:

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Supplement[] supplements = new Supplement[4];

        fillArray(supplements);

        Magazine magazineobj = new Magazine("The Wheels Special", 35, supplements);
        magazineobj.printMagazine();

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you try to do ? Here you call an instance method from a static context... It can't work

Comment: You should make this method `static` and call it like this: `Supplement.fillArray(supplements);`

Comment: That seems to let me compile now. However, nothing gets printed out. Is there something wrong with my print method in Magazine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the method `fillArray` `static` to access it without an instance of `Supplement` because in the `JavaApplication1` class is no method called `fillArray` is `static` or can be accessed by a static context.

Use:

```java
public static void fillArray(Supplement[] supplements) { ... }
```

Call:

```java
Supplement.fillArray(suplements);
```

Comment: That seems to let me compile now. However, nothing gets printed out. Is there something wrong with my print method in Magazine?

Comment: It is because the field `magazineobj` in the `Magazine` instance is null. Also, you don't overwrite the `toString` method. You can try `System.out.println(magazineobj)` in the `main`-method but that will just print the name and the memory address of the object when you don't overwrite `toString()`.